# Serializing TypeScript object to xml with xsd

Tags: xml, typescript, serialization, xsd, deserialization

I'm trying to serialize a given TypeScript object as a string.

I have used [cxsd](https://github.com/charto/cxsd) to generate TypeScript definition files from my xsd, and was able to parse the string as my object using:

```
import * as cxml from 'cxml';
import * as example from 'assets/xmlns/www.example.com/OrderDefinition';

export class SerializerService {

  constructor() {}

  async unmarshal(contents: string): Promise<OrderDefinition> {

    let parser = new cxml.Parser();
    let result = await parser.parse(contents, example.document);

    return result;
  }
}
```

Can anyone help with serializing the object back into a string that complies with my XSD.

I'm sure there's a simple answer that I'm overlooking.

Comment: Yeah, that is exactly what I am looking for - simply said, how to use cxsd? Did You managed to generate XML properly?

Comment: Do you all manage to generate XML data ?

Comment: Hi,  that is exactly what I am looking for too, there is a solution?